# Recuperar variable de una URL

Tags: php, sql, php5

Paso el valor de la siguiente manera:

```
<td><a href="liberar.php?id='.$row["id"].'">Finalizar</a> </td>
```

Y en la URL llega de esta forma:

```
 000.000.00.00/bitacora/liberar.php?id=11
```

id=11 es valor que quiero recuperar

Para recuperar el id en (liberar.php) tengo lo siguiente:

```
include("database.php");


$folio =  $_GET['id'];

echo("Soy folio", $folio);
$id = 0;

$db = new database();
$id = $db->finalizaActividad($folio);
?>
```

Posteriormente ese folio lo envio a una consulta que se llama finalizaActividad

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema?¿qué es lo que falla?

Comment: @Yo Albert No logro recuperar la variable: id en liberar,php

Comment: Muestra algún error??? que trae la variable???

Comment: @MarcoIzaguirre no me mustra nada, pero si entra a liberar.php es decir: 000.000.00.00/bitacora/liberar.php?id=11

Comment: @NetzaL cuando se ejecuta esta linea echo("Soy folio", $folio); te aparece solo la palabra "Soy folio" ?

Comment: @YoAlbert Si, solo la palabra Soy folio...

Comment: @NetzaL intenta reemplazar la linea del hecho que tiene por: echo "Soy folio". $folio;

Comment: @YoAlbert si, era el echo...

Comment: @NetzaL he colocado como respuesta la solución saludos.

Comment: @NetzaL Si se soluciono tu problema, marca la respuesta correcta ya que puede servir para otros :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es el echo;

```
echo("Soy folio", $folio);
```

Debería estar así:

```
 echo "Soy folio". $folio;
```